# CLI Solution - Stripping File Attributes - LSOpenURLsWithRole()

Tags: macos, command-line, error, metadata, gatekeeper

I am getting this error when trying to execute an unsigned application that was downloaded via the native web-browser; `Safari.app`.

```
LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -10810..
```

There used to be a solution to a similar question on AskDifferent that *utilised the CLI to strip certain attributes* from the file in question, allowing it to run. It was a good solution but it has since been deleted and now I've forgotten what it was.

Does anybody know the command('s?) that I'm referring to?

Comment: Could you show your research? When you say "there used to be a solution" that doesn't show what you did now to research your problem. See http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask a good question per the site's guidelines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's `xattr -rc app-name`, but I could be completely wrong.

Comment: I think you might be on the right track.. I recall there being more to it though..